Verify signature generate by hashicorp vault using node crypt library
I'm unable to verify a signature generated by Hashicorp vault using the node crypto library.
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
// const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./private1.key');
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('./hashicorp.key', 'utf8');

const data = Buffer.from("test", "utf-8");
const data1 = data.toString('base64');
console.log(data1);
// sample signature generated for data - {"input": "dGVzdA=="}
const signature = "X2+xXGSnc/Vdk3KvPMlnHqT4uMMC6oAB+FHlQWvpoKXwAH+dFwX6uodPH7fCw1uQyQ4B7yuNATBYju/UDsosBiGBNUopzTMwoASACPA2Neo+jfgvBfAkC/LJMJ7pHZI3pkoIt43/QxjhjW1tHu7S5jfjTG0YaYe2vWstiuT7HcWpU0giVBKcN6oTBm9kcgMoTAEWFnqre7q1QpPXLEaQUJB4veQhcDR1us8B4cK6EhP8kNdu6a3x2FKw9CWiORv1lr/lB+yV1Y2mShkLL3uBgvQTswq9wqRBv57mX6O8nLXADkn+t4N4LIpyy3M0VdWcOVkpaCqLsnA8u76f32HArA==";
// crypto.sign('RSA-SHA256', data1, privateKey); 
const verify = crypto.verify('SHA256', data1, publicKey, Buffer.from(signature, 'base64'));

console.log("Is Valid - ", verify);

// Is  Valid - false

They have very less document to use in any SDK - https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/secret/transit#signature
I have created key pair in hashicorp vault and generated a signature using the api
https://vault.com/v1/transit/sign/some_key_ring_name/sha2-256
I got the public key from vault and using it on local machine.
I can verify using vault api but not using node's crypto library.

...I have created key pair...using api... The link does not seem to work! Post consistent test data (including non-productive keys).
